# QSqlTableModel vs QSqlQuery, which is fast (over the internet)?

Tags: qt

I need to pull some data from a MySQL server over the internet and show in a QTableView. From the experience I have (not so much) working with both, QSqlTableModel and QSqlQuery, it seems (in general) QSqlTableModel is slower. Is it true?

Comment: why don't you profile it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two different mechanisms:

- The TableModel is used to display some (remote) data in (local) TableView.
- The SQLQuery is used to create SQLQuerys.

Usually QSQLTableModel is bound to a single database-Table or View, and shows/edits the data in visible range. No query is needed. The QSQLTableModel is optimised for edit SQL-table data in TableViews. I don't think that some hand-implemented code is 'faster' for this.

On the other hand: If you need Queries (i.e. if your application uses data from sql-joins, or 'crate table' query etc...) the QSqlQuery is optimised to create such queries. The result QSQLRecord is a fast accessible class, and can be used fast.